# can dhcp, or domain controller, update time in client machine

Tags: dhcp, domain-controller

I want to update the time on client machines in my domain.

Can DHCP or Domain Controller update the windows time in client machines ?? if Yes, how to do that ?

Please include steps

Answer (score 4):

Yep, DHCP can pass [Option 42](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzakg/rzakgconceptoptions.htm) NTP details easily, as can a correctly setup AD server/client system.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not specialist, could you please tell me how to do this in Microsoft Windows Server 2003 ?

Comment: This site is for PROFESSIONAL sysadmins, not beginners, please do some basic homework first before coming here, seriously how hard is it to google "configure dhcp options windows"??

Answer (score 1):

Please refer following urls for your needs.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758905%28WS.10%29.aspx

http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-nt/how-do-i-enable-domain-users-to-update-system-time-from-the-server/6004.html

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if your Client is a member of a AD Domain the Clients gets the time automaticaly from its domain controller.